# loops, list, python 3.x

Tags: python, loops, process

trying to create a two column table that uses a loop to read and process.  trying to create a list that shows a integer and it square root. I have played with the program several ways but cannot figure out why i am getting an invalid syntax.

```
"""with open('numbers.txt', 'w') as file:
for i in range(5): #The loop
    number = 0
    while (number < 10) or (number > 50):
        number = int(input("Enter integer {0}:  ".format(i+1)))
    number_str = "{0}\n".format(number)
    file.write(number_str)
file.close()"""
```

with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as file:

```
import math 

print ("\nInteger\t\tSquare Root")

while True:
    line = file.readline() 

    if len(line) == 0:
        break

    number = int(line) 
    square_root = math.sqrt(number) 

    print (number, "\t\t\t%.4f" % round(square_root, 4)

file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket on the penultimate line. It should be:

```
print (number, "\t\t\t%.4f" % round(square_root, 4))
```